# change password in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i write code for change password but it does not change the password in table
but make 0 current password.So what i do.Thanks

THis is my Model

```
function changepassword() {
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
$this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('OldPassword'));
$query = $this->db->get('mau_user');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $row = $query->row();
    if ($row->id === $this->session->userdata('id')) {
        $data = array(
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $this->db->where('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('OldPassword'));
        if ($this->db->update('mau_user', $data)) {
            return "Password Changed Successfully";
```

Comment: did you check the value of `$this->input->post('password')` ?

Comment: just an info: its better to filter the user inputs in your controller and pass on to your model rather than passing it directly..

Comment: not related to your question, but try to encrypt the password (md5) before save into db.

Comment: As @Jurgo has suggested, make sure your post values are correct first.

Answer (score 0):

If in the db the field password is set as an integer, the default value is 0, so probably the value you're tryn' to update it's invalid, you should print the SQL and start debuggin from there....

Comment: It's possible that the value is actually false (because it doesn't exist) and the database is converting that to 0.

Comment: Default value might be not 0 for an integer, it might be any integer actually, if default is defined in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
function edit_password()
{
    $uderid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    // update data

    if($_POST)
    {
        if($this->input->post('old_password')!=''){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('old_password','Old password',  'trim|required|xss_clean|addslashes|encode_php_tags |callback_oldpass_check');            
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password','New password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|addslashes|encode_php_tags|min_length['.PASS_MIN_LEN.']|md5');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|addslashes|encode_php_tags|min_length['.PASS_MIN_LEN.']|matches[new_password]|md5');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) 
            {       
                $data =array( 'password' => $this->input->post('conf_password'));                   
                $this->main->update('users','user_id',$uderid,$data);

                $this->change_password('Password updated successfully');                      
            }
            else{
                $this->change_password();
                }       
            }

        else{
            redirect(base_url().'user' , '301');
        }
    }       

}

 function oldpass_check($oldpass)
 {  
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $result = $this->main->check_oldpassword($oldpass,$user_id);       
        if($result ==0)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('oldpass_check', "%s doesn't match.");
                return FALSE ;  

            }
         else
            {
                return TRUE ;

            }             
}
```

Model

```
function check_oldpassword($oldpass,$user_id)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($oldpass));        
    $query = $this->db->get('users'); //data table
    return $query->num_rows(); 
}
```